# Android Studio Listview for loop adapter update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

i have a question, i have a for loop, that loops through an arraylist and checks if a value is something, and if so, it deletes an row in a listview....I am having trouble though, this is the code...

```js
 for (int i=0; i<displayList.size(); i++)
                {
                    Object toRemove = mAdapter.getItem(i);
                    Log.e("Counter+++",String.valueOf(i));

                    if (!firstname.equals("")) {
                        if (firstnamefilterstring.equals("Contains"))
                        {
                            if (!displayList.get(i).getFirstname().contains(firstname))
                            {
                                //displayList.remove(listView.getItemAtPosition(i));   doesnt work
                               // displayList.remove(toRemove); doesnt work either
                                L.e("1");
                            }
```

The problem is through debugging I have realized this loop only runs 6/12 times (the for loop is 12 elements big), and I have no clue why... Through some additional debugging, I realized that the two lines with "doesnt work" if you comment them out, it runs fine (12 times), but with either of those two lines it doesnt....Im at a lost here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it runs half the time is you are removing items from your display List, hence `displayList.remove`.

> The java.util.ArrayList.remove(int index) method removes the element
>   at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements
>   to the left (subtracts one from their indices).